# How can I create Layered Navigation Filters on MobileApp using APIs?

Tags: magento2, api, layered-navigation

I want to create the layered navigation filters for my mobileapp the same way it is working on web how can i do this kindly guide

Thanks in advanced

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento already have built in graphql query for that first use product query to get product data and then  use this for this for layered naviagtion

Magento official doc for graphql you can find all queries and mutation here
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/

you can enable layered navigation for your customer attribute and add it here using match if you need an eq and in filter then let me know i will update the ans.

```
{
  products(filter: { category_id: { in: "12" }, color: { eq: "5480" }, price: {from: "40" to: "59"} }) {
    total_count
    aggregations {
      count
      attribute_code
      label
      options {
        label
        value
      }
    }
    items {
      id
      sku
      name
    }
  }
}
```